# pass kinit a custom krb5.conf file

Tags: kerberos

I'm using kinit to log into a server that my sys admin didn't anticipate us using. It seems that the default location for the config file is `/etc/krb5.conf`, but I don't have root access so I can't edit this file to add a new server. How can I pass kinit a custom config file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

OK, solved the problem: the default config file location can be overridden by setting the [`KRB5_CONFIG` environment variable](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-current/doc/user/user_config/kerberos.html#kerberos-7)

Comment: I need the same for java kinit command. Is there any Environment variable for it?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue today. Here's the command that worked for me, for future reference:

```
env KRB5_CONFIG=/path/to/custom/krb5.conf kinit <your..args..here>
```

Answer (score 17):

Try using

on Win
**`-Djava.security.krb5.conf=C:/IBM/IBMSSO/krb5.ini`**

on non Win
**`-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/opt/IBM/IBMSSO/krb5.conf`**

Example on Windows (with IBM Java)

```
java -Djava.security.krb5.conf=C:/IBM/IBMSSO/krb5.ini com.ibm.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit -k -t C:/IBM/IBMSSO/SSOICNTilo.keytab HTTP/myserver.123.com@123.COM
```

Comment: For kinit.exe, the parameter has to be in quotes: `kinit.exe -J-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -J-D"java.security.krb5.conf=C:\mypath\my_krb5.ini"`

Answer (score 0):

This is work fine on centos.

```
export KRB5_CONFIG=/your_krb5_conf_path
```

Comment: Isn’t this exactly what’s already been proposed?